# Scrolling Inside Div Not Working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a modal which I am using for alphabetical searching. Along the top, there is a horizontal bar with A-Z buttons. I want each of these buttons to scroll the div (with overflow:auto) to the appropriate letter.

Eg if the user clicks "G", it will scroll the div down to the G results.

I would like to set these onclicks with js or jquery. Here's what I have so far:

```
$('.search__strip__letter').each(function () {
    var number = $(this).data('letter');
    $(this).click(function () {
        var target = '#search__results__letter--'+number;
        $('.search-results').animate({scrollTop:$(target).position().top}, 200);
    })
})
```

Why isn't this working...?

**EDIT:** [Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g84nsggm/).

Comment: Can you add a fiddle to replicate the issue ?

Comment: perhaps try `.offset().top` instead of `.position().top` as position is relative to the parent and offset is relative to the entire document

Comment: if it's a modal I think you must add this script inline in the view which is loaded in the new modal window..

Comment: @MateiMihai It makes no difference if the script is inline.

Comment: Add a fiddle and I will fix it

Comment: @Aerious Check my edit

Comment: @JohnDoe http://jsfiddle.net/Aerious/z17nyh2s/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

You should be using [`$(target).offset().top`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/), it works independent of the style's `position` property.

You must `scrollTop` to `0` and subtract the `.search-results` offset's top, also.

**UPDATE II**

If you want to animate for both sides, instead of scrollingTop to `0`, you must get the current scrollTop and sum it, take a look below:

```js
[].forEach.call('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', function(l, i) {
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.textContent = l;
  a.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var target = '#search__results__letter--' + i;
    var now = $('.search-results').scrollTop();
    $('.search-results').animate({ scrollTop: $(target).offset().top - $('.search-results').offset().top + now }, 200);
  });
  document.getElementById('letters').appendChild(a);
  
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.id = 'search__results__letter--' + i;
  div.textContent = 'Letter ' + l;
  
  document.querySelector('.search-results').appendChild(div);
});
```

```css
#letters a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: darkblue;
  margin: 2px;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: Verdana;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.search-results {
  height: 120px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.search-results div {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: aqua;
  margin: 2px;
  font-family: Verdana;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="letters">
</div>
<div class="search-results">
</div>
```

Comment: Don't know who did it, but what you said is true and should help

Comment: @Buzinas This actually doesn't make a difference

Comment: I down voted for the comment on `position:absolute` and `position:fixed`.  This is incorrect.  The only position attribute necessary is `position:relative` (or a position attribute other than `static`, but in most cases, `relative` is best as it maintains normal document flow) on the *** .search-results*** element.  `target` should remain either `static` or `relative`.  Making it `absolute` or `fixed` will take it out of flow.  This will completely destroy scrolling to those elements.  The will not exist in normal flow and thus cannot be scrolled to.

Comment: @JosephMarikle thanks for informing me, I updated my answer :)

Comment: @Buzinas This looks great, but if you select a previous letter, it doesn't animate back up. Eg select C, and then select A. The transition to the top of A isn't animated.

Answer (score 3):

Added clearfix class on floated elements, updated jquery selector spelling Fixed here.
  `$('.search__strip__letter').each(function () {
    var number = $(this).data('letter');
    $(this).click(function () {
        console.log('click');
        var target = '#search__results__letter--' + number;
        console.log(target,$('.search-results'));
        $('.search-results').animate({
            scrollTop: $(target).offset().top + 100
        }, 200);
    })
})`

http://jsfiddle.net/Aerious/z17nyh2s/8/

Comment: This doesn't work.  Try clicking "B" twice in your demo.

Answer (score 0):

You need a couple modifications to your code to make it work as I understand it.  First, you need to give the `.search-results` element some context.  You do this by adding `position:relative` to that element.  Now that it's the relative parent of your `search__results__letter--*` elements, you can scroll to them with your animate snippet.  However, you also need to calculate the scroll position relative to the offset scroll of the parent.  Simple math will handle that part by first getting the scroll position of the `search__results__letter--*` element and adding it to the `scrollTop()` of `.search-results`.  You can see this method in the demo code below:

```js
$('.search__strip__letter').each(function () {
    var number = $(this).data('letter');
    $(this).on('click', function () {
        var target = '#search__results__letter--'+number;
        var currentPosition = $('.search-results').scrollTop();
        $('.search-results').animate({scrollTop:currentPosition + $(target).position().top}, 200);
    })
})
```

```css
.search-results {
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="search__strip__letter" data-letter="A">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="search__strip__letter" data-letter="B">B</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="search__strip__letter" data-letter="C">C</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="search__strip__letter" data-letter="D">D</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="search__strip__letter" data-letter="E">E</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="search__strip__letter" data-letter="F">F</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="search-results">
    <p id="search__results__letter--A">Search Results A</p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p id="search__results__letter--B">Search Results B</p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p id="search__results__letter--C">Search Results C</p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p id="search__results__letter--D">Search Results D</p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p id="search__results__letter--E">Search Results E</p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p id="search__results__letter--F">Search Results F</p>
</div>
```

#### EDIT:

I've adapted the original poster's fiddle using my code.  One addition I had to make was to force the `.search__results__letter` back into flow by making a new [block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting) on that class.  I did this by adding `display:inline-block;width:100%;`  Adding `overflow:hidden;` or `overflow:auto;` should also accomplish the same thing.  Also, see [MDN docs on block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context) for other methods to force it.

https://jsfiddle.net/gLpvzgu5/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the [jquery.scrollTo](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo) plugin. It's highly customizable, supports animations and is very easy to use. You just need to replace your `animate` code with something like this:

```
$('.search-results').scrollTo($(target), 200);
```

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote? I simply suggested that he should use a plugin to handle the animation instead of calculating the offset by himself.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote was cast.  Seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/qno7uk07/.  Maybe next time you could make a demo showing that it does work.